# Getting a File's MD5 on Dropzone.js

Tags: javascript, hash, dropzone.js

I would like to calculate an MD5 checksum of every image uploaded with Dropzone.js, this way the user can safely remove the correct image (I calculate the MD5 Checksum in php part).

I need to create the MD5 hash with another library ([FastMD5](https://github.com/iReal/FastMD5) or another one), and then send it along with the data when remove button is clicked.

For now:

```
$Dropzone.autoDiscover = false;
    // Dropzone class:
    var myDropzone = new Dropzone("div#dropzonePreview", { 
        maxFiles:5,
        url: "up",
        acceptedFiles: ".png,.jpg,.gif,.jpeg",
        maxFilesize: 6,
        uploadMultiple: true,
        addRemoveLinks: true,

        removedfile: function(file) {
            var name = file.name;  
            var idform = document.getElementById('idform').value; //for me 
            var hash= md5(file); // not tested
            $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url: 'del.php',
                data:"filename="+name+"&idform="+idform+"&hash="+hash,
                dataType: 'html'
            });
        var _ref;
        return (_ref = file.previewElement) != null ? _ref.parentNode.removeChild(file.previewElement) : void 0;        
      }

    });
```

The problem is that md5(file) is not working, I guess it isn't the data file, I tried to look for the data to calculate the hash but found nothing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm sure there is a better way to do it, but I've made this and it's sending the right hash to my delete page (del.php), I've just realised that I will also need the hash to avoid the upload of the same file 2 times..

I've used [SPARK-MD5](https://github.com/satazor/SparkMD5).

```
    Dropzone.autoDiscover = false;
        // Dropzone class:
        var myDropzone = new Dropzone("div#dropzonePreview", { 
            maxFiles:5,
            url: "upload.php",
            acceptedFiles: ".png,.jpg,.gif,.jpeg",
            maxFilesize: 6,
            uploadMultiple: true,
            addRemoveLinks: true,

        //to remove one file
            removedfile: function(file) {
                var name = file.name;  
                var idform = document.getElementById('idform').value; //for me
                // START SPARKMD5
                var blobSlice = File.prototype.slice || File.prototype.mozSlice || File.prototype.webkitSlice,
                    chunkSize = 2097152,                             // Read in chunks of 2MB
                    chunks = Math.ceil(file.size / chunkSize),
                    currentChunk = 0,
                    spark = new SparkMD5.ArrayBuffer(),
                    fileReader = new FileReader();

                fileReader.onload = function (e) {
                    console.log('read chunk nr', currentChunk + 1, 'of', chunks);
                    spark.append(e.target.result);                   // Append array buffer
                    currentChunk++;

                    if (currentChunk < chunks) {
                        loadNext();
                    } else {
                        console.log('finished loading');
                       // START DROPZONE PART
                        $.ajax({
                            type: 'POST',
                            url: 'del.php',
                            data:"filename="+name+"&idform="+idform+"&hash="+spark.end(), //spark.end is the MD5
                            dataType: 'html'
                        });
                        var _ref;
                        return (_ref = file.previewElement) != null ? _ref.parentNode.removeChild(file.previewElement) : void 0; 
                        // END DROPZONE PART
                    }
                };

                fileReader.onerror = function () {
                    console.warn('oops, something went wrong.');
                };

                function loadNext() {
                    var start = currentChunk * chunkSize,
                        end = ((start + chunkSize) >= file.size) ? file.size : start + chunkSize;

                    fileReader.readAsArrayBuffer(blobSlice.call(file, start, end));
                }

                loadNext();
                // END SPARKMD5
          }
});
```

I'm not sure about the necessity of fileReader.onerror and load next.
Anyway it's working when the need is to send the hash when the "remove" button is clicked, but i'm still looking for a better way to compare md5 before uploading.